# Javascript with localstorage check

Tags: javascript, html

```
var site = document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("site").value;

var link = document.getElementById('displayy').innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("link").value;

var t = true;


var both = [site,link];
while (t == true){

    var s = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var check = localStorage.getItem(y);

    if (check === null){

        localStorage.setItem(s , both);
        alert(y);
        break;

    } else {

        var s = s + 1;
        var y = y + 1;
        localStorage.setItem(s , both);    

    }

}
```

Javascript should check if 0 = emty if so then add it to localstorarge if no check 1 check 2 check 3 etc. I get the data from html.

Comment: what do you mean `0 = emty` ?

Comment: Both variables `s` and `y` are set to `0` at the start of the loop your else makes no sense then.

Comment: so what is actually the question?

Comment: Why `s` and `y` ? They always share the same value, you could have a single variable. Why do you break if you loop on `t` ? Why not looping on `check !== null` ?

Comment: Its starts with 0 because thats the first var in localstorage en then 1 2 3 4 if it worked

Comment: You will need to serialize and deserialize your array since `localStorage` only support strings

Comment: What the point of storing same value x times ?

Comment: whats the point because value x can be your dogs name and my dogs name and i want to enter them both and display them both

Comment: @Pretpacked, If I understand well, what you are trying to do is if(check ===1) {store (1)} if(check ===2) {store(2)}, etc... Is that what you tried to do?

Comment: yes @edkeveked thats what im trying to do ty

Comment: @Pretpacked, you could see my answer to the question